# Limit number of places in php

Tags: php

i am wondering how to limit some numbers etc:
This number: 90.909090909091
just to: 90.90

I am using math here,

```
$var1share = $adamage / ($adamage + $ddamage) * 100;
```

So, i want $varshare output to be in format: 90.90, no: 90.909090909091, if you understand...
Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Use the [number_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function or [sprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) when echoing the value

Comment: Can you explain more, or give me example? thanks :) i am new

Comment: The documentation links in my comment should help, and provide plenty of examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) function:

```
$var1share = $adamage / ($adamage + $ddamage) * 100;
$var1share = round(var1share, 2);
```

Comment: wow thanks, that really works and helps me! :) wi will mark this as right answer, i cant now, i need wait 11 minutes :) thanks!

Comment: disagree. round returns also a float, so numeric unstable. sprintf returns a string.